# После союза И — новое предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении: "Отчего-то снова захотелось уехать отсюда(,) и в этот раз окончательно и бесповоротно"?

Напишите, пожалуйста, причину её постановки или непостановки. Меня надолго переклинило с этим, думаю, не начинается ли второе простое предложение после первого союза.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Отчего-то снова захотелось уехать отсюда, и в этот раз окончательно и бесповоротно.**

Запятая ставится, так как союз И — присоединительный.

Оборот **"на этот раз окончательно и бесповоротно"** состоит из  обстоятельств времени и образа действия.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

5. Следует различать присоединительные союзы и соединительные союзы и, да, связывающие однородные члены предложения: **перед присоединительным союзом ставится запятая,** а перед неповторяющимся соединительным союзом никакого знака не требуется. Ср.:
   Автор статью представил, **и своевременно** (и — союз присоединительный).

Comment: В данном случае присоединительная конструкция не является предложением (см. вопрос).

Comment: Да, не является, иначе здесь использовались бы другие присоединительные союзы, например:  Отчего-то снова захотелось уехать отсюда, причем в этот раз это решение казалось мне окончательным и бесповоротным.